# Create Loop So Whole Task Repeats

Tags: loops, python-3.x, nested

```
import sgenrand

# program greeting 

print("The purpose of this exercise is to enter a number of coin values") 

print("that add up to a displayed target value.\n") 

print("Enter coins values as 1-penny, 5-nickel, 10-dime,and 25-quarter.") 

print("Hit return after the last entered coin value.")

print("--------------------") 

#print("Enter coins that add up to 81 cents, one per line.")

total = 0 

#prompt the user to start entering coin values that add up to 81  
    while True: 

    final_coin= sgenrand.randint(1,99)

    print ("Enter coins that add up to", final_coin, "cents, on per line") 

    user_input = int(input("Enter first coin: "))

    if user_input != 1 and user_input!=5 and user_input!=10 and user_input!=25:
        print("invalid input")
        total = total + user_input

    while total != final_coin:
        user_input = int(input("Enter next coin:"))
        total = total + user_input 

    if user_input == input(" "):
        break 
    if total > final_coin:
         print("Sorry - total amount exceeds", (final_coin)) 

    if total < final_coin:
        print("Sorry - you only entered",(total))
    if total== final_coin: 
        print("correct")    


    goagain= input("Try again (y/n)?:") 

    if goagain == "y":
        if goagain == "n":
          print("Thanks for playing ... goodbye!" )
```

I've been trying to create this loop, so it can repeat the whole program at the end when the user accepts/ if he accepts to do it again at the end.

I know you have to have a while statement around your whole program, but with my `while true` statement at the top, it only repeats the first part of my program and not the whole thing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well one thing you should be careful of is that you do not set the

```
total = 0
```

at the start of each loop. So when the user plays the game again. He will continue using his previous total. You should move `total = 0` to the start of the loop

```
while True:
    total = 0
```

Additionally, you need to deindent you first

```
while True
```

statement as it does not align properly with the rest of your code.

Finally, you need to allow the user to exit the while loop after he selects No for trying again.

```
if goagain == "n":
    print("Thanks for playing ... goodbye!" )
    break
```

This can be done by applying a `break` statement.